# ImportError: /home/kei/darkflow/darkflow/cython_utils/cy_yolo_findboxes.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, cython, yolo, darkflow

I have an ImportError:

```
(tensorflow) kei@giga:~/darkflow$ ./flow --model cfg/yolo.cfg --load yolo.weights --savepb
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./flow", line 4, in 
from darkflow.cli import cliHandler
File "/home/kei/darkflow/darkflow/cli.py", line 3, in 
from .net.build import TFNet
File "/home/kei/darkflow/darkflow/net/build.py", line 7, in 
from .framework import create_framework
File "/home/kei/darkflow/darkflow/net/framework.py", line 1, in 
from . import yolo
File "/home/kei/darkflow/darkflow/net/yolo/init.py", line 2, in 
from . import predict
File "/home/kei/darkflow/darkflow/net/yolo/predict.py", line 7, in 
from ...cython_utils.cy_yolo_findboxes import yolo_box_constructor
ImportError: /home/kei/darkflow/darkflow/cython_utils/cy_yolo_findboxes.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

What can I do?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You have a mixed compilation issue. Did you tried to build with Python 2.7 or 3.x, or something like that? Best is to clean completely your project, and rebuild with the intented version.

Comment: After running $ pip install cython, I think no error came out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I fixed it by cleaning and rebuilding the application in Cython

```
setup.py clean --all
```